# Wildcard redirect at end of url in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I couldn't find an accurate solution for this on SO.

I have a Wordpress site that needs any URL that contains /blog/?p* to redirect to /blog

The * denotes the wildcard point. So any URL that starts with /blog/?p gets redirected.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/?p.*$ http://website.com/blog
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: If you mean `?p` as a query string and not a regex, that is not possible from a `RewriteRule` alone you will have to use a `RewriteCond` as well.

Comment: Would it actually make more sense to use RedirectMatch 301 ?

Comment: And yes `?p` is meant as query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern (the first argument of `RewriteRule`) only matches the part before the `?` (the path). To match the part after the `?` (the query string), you need to use a `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

So for instance:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p
RewriteRule ^/?blog/ http://target
```